# Not clear about the meaning of auto.offset.reset and enable.auto.commit in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka,and I don't really understand the meaning of Kafka configuration, can anyone explain in a more understandable way to me?

Here is my code:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "master:9092,slave1:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "GROUP_2017",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest", //earliest or latest
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean)
)
```

what does it mean in my code?

Comment: I suggest reading the Kafka documentation that is relevant to the version of Kafka that you are reading from and/or writing to: [Here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html) is the official documentation. The section on Consumer and Producer configs has definitions for the parameters.

Comment: Much better question and set of answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390265/what-determines-kafka-consumer-offset

Answer (score 27):

I will explain to you the meaning, but I highly suggest to read [Kafka Web Site Configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs)

```
"bootstrap.servers" -> "master:9092,slave1:9092"
```

Essentially the Kafka cluster configuration: IP and Port.

```
 "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer]
 "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer]
```

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872520/whats-the-purpose-of-kafkas-key-value-pair-based-messaging) answer explain what is the purpose.

```
"group.id" -> "GROUP_2017"
```

A consumer process will belong to a consumer "group". A group can have multiple consumers and Kafka will assign exactly one consumer process to each partition (for consuming messages). If the number of consumers is greater than number of partitions available, then some consumer processes will be idle.

```
"enable.auto.commit" -> (true: java.lang.Boolean)
```

When that flag is true, Kafka is able to commit the message you brought from Kafka using Zookeeper to persist the last 'offset' which it read. This approach is not the best to use when you want a more robust solution for a production system, because does not ensure that the records you brought were correctly processed (using the logic you wrote in your code). If this flag is false, Kafka will not know which was the last offset read so when you restart the process, it will start reading the 'earliest' or the 'latest' offset depending on the value of your next flag (auto.offset.reset). Finally, [This Cloudera article](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/06/offset-management-for-apache-kafka-with-apache-spark-streaming/) explains in details how to manage in a proper way the offsets.

```
"auto.offset.reset" -> "latest"
```

This flag tells Kafka where to start reading offsets in case you do not have any 'commit' yet. In others words, it will start either from the 'earliest' or from the 'latest' if you have not persisted any offset in Zookeeper yet (Manually or using enable.auto.commit flag).

Comment: "auto.offset.reset" -> "largest"

Comment: `largest` for older consumers, `latest` for newer ones.

Comment: @dbustosp what will be the robust way to set offset to latest?

Comment: How is smallest/earliest defined? Smallest of what?

Comment: @user1491636 offset of the message which will be read after the Consumer either start or restarting. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48320672/what-is-the-difference-between-kafka-earliest-and-latest-offset-values

Comment: @ShalabhNegi What I did at that time for the application which is now in Production is to use Apache Zookeeper to track the offsets for the Consumers.

Comment: So "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest/end" is usable only when  "enable.auto.commit" is set to false?
Let me know about this, been stuck on this.

Answer (score 7):

`auto.offset.reset` is ONLY at play when there is no valid committed offset; such as at the first time you start the system, or after a committed offset expires and is deleted because its too old.

`enable.auto.commit` is about a choice to have offsets committed automatically in the background vs explicit manual control in the foreground.

```
auto.offset.reset
```

What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):

- `earliest`: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
- `latest`: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset
- `none`: throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group
- anything else: throw exception to the consumer.

```
Type:
string
Default:
latest
Valid Values:
[latest, earliest, none]
Importance:
medium
```

```
enable.auto.commit
```

If true, the consumer's offset will be periodically committed in the background.

```
Type:
boolean
Default:
true
Valid Values:

Importance:
medium
```

```
auto.commit.interval.ms
```

The frequency in milliseconds that the consumer offsets are auto-committed to Kafka if `enable.auto.commit` is set to `true`.

```
Type:
int
Default:
5000 (5 seconds)
Valid Values:
[0,...]
Importance:
low
```

The full set of consumer configuration parameters in documented on the Apache Kafka web site at https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#newconsumerconfigs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28078447)

Comment: good feedback. fixed the answer with useful context and in place documentation that wont expire if the link changes

Answer (score 6):

Adding more details on configurations mentioned in the title: "Not clear about the meaning of `auto.offset.reset` and `enable.auto.commit` in Kafka"

#### [auto.offset.reset](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#auto.offset.reset)

With the `auto.offset.reset` configuration you can steer the behavior of your consumer (as part of a consumer group) in situations when your Consumer Group has never consumed and committed from a particular topic or the last committed offset from that Consumer Group was deleted (e.g. through cleanup policy).

Each message in a partition of a Kafka topic has a unique identifier which is the `offset`. Offsets are unique per Kafka partition. A consumer usually commits back the offsets on each partition of the topic it consumed. That way, the consumer is able to avoid duplicate readings.

Imagine you have a consumer reading from a topic for the first time (or if you change the consumer group name). The consumer group has therefore never committed any offsets. According to the [Config Docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#auto.offset.reset) you can choose between the following behaviors with the configuration `auto.offset.reset`:

- *earliest:* automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
- *latest:* automatically reset the offset to the latest offset
- *none:* throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group
- *anything else:* throw exception to the consumer.

The default setting is `latest`.

#### [enable.auto.commit](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#enable.auto.commit)

As mentioned above it is critical to think about your offsets and their commits when consuming messages from Kafka. When setting the configuration `enable.auto.commit` to `true` the consumer offsets will be committed automatically in the background.

In the [JavaDocs of KafkaConsumer](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#offset-management) you will find a nice example on how to manually commit the offsets in a Consumer Client using

```java
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
consumer.commitSync();
```

To emphasize the importance of the Offset Management in you consumer client again it is worth reading the whole Java Docs description or the [confluent Kafka Documentation on Offset Management](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/consumer.html#offset-management).