# Can't get kafka consumer records with AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG = "latest"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a test automation project. I'm trying to get kafka consumer records starting from the latest record with config `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG = "latest"`. But it doesn't work. Here is a code where I'm trying to poll data:

```
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500L));
            value = findValue(key, consumerRecords);
            if(value != null){
                break;
            }
        }
```

In this code variable `consumerRecords` has 0 size in every iteration.

If I change `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `"earliest"` then `consumer.poll()` works and variable `consumerRecords` has not 0 size, but elements in collection are starting since earliest offset, while I need elements which are starting since last offset.

How I can achieve `consumerRecords` with elements in decreasing order by offset ?

I tried to increase the timeout to polling up to 10 seconds - it didn't help.

kafka-clients:2.7.0

Answer (score 0):

With consumer `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG = "latest"` the consumer will get any record only if after the consumer is started there are records getting produced to the topic. You are getting records for `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG = "earliest"` because there are records already present in the topic. You can get more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48320672/7726319)

Answer (score 0):

> I need elements which are starting since last offset.

Then you'll want to run some producer after the consumer has started from the end of the topic, where there is no data (yet). During an automated test, though, having only 20 polls from the end of the topic might yield a race condition in which the consumer could finish before the producer actually sends anything.

> with elements in decreasing order by offset ?

It is not feasible to iterate a Kafka topic backwards

Comment: Well, if you really want to iterate a topic backwards you can use the Consumer.seek method together with batch size config.
I wouldn't advise to do so though, maybe it could be fine in a test.

Comment: It'd be really slow since you'd need to consume and seek one record offset at a time